# How to install wine via brew?

Tags: osx, wine, homebrew

I am trying to install wine via homebrew on Mac OS Mountain Lion 10.8.4.

```
$ brew install wine
Error: wine dependency jpeg not installed with:
  --universal
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Found this over on the AskDifferent site, in a Q&A titled: [Installing wine with homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68426/installing-wine-with-homebrew). The workaround listed in that Q&A was to do the following:

```
$ brew rm jpeg
$ brew install jpeg --universal
```

This was the issue filed on github for `brew`: [Brew does not upgrade existing dependencies to --universal](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18888).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
brew install cask wine-stable
```